# matplotlib get ylim values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using `matplotlib` to plot data (using `plot` and `errorbar` functions) from Python.  I have to plot a set of totally separate and independent plots, and then adjust their `ylim` values so they can be easily visually compared.

How can I retrieve the `ylim` values from each plot, so that I can take the min and max of the lower and upper ylim values, respectively, and adjust the plots so they can be visually compared?

Of course, I could just analyze the data and come up with my own custom `ylim` values... but I'd like to use `matplotlib` to do that for me.  Any suggestions on how to easily (and efficiently) do this?

Here's my Python function that plots using `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myplotfunction(title, values, errors, plot_file_name):

    # plot errorbars
    indices = range(0, len(values))
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.errorbar(tuple(indices), tuple(values), tuple(errors), marker='.')

    # axes
    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_xlim([-0.5, len(values) - 0.5])
    axes.set_xlabel('My x-axis title')
    axes.set_ylabel('My y-axis title')

    # title
    plt.title(title)

    # save as file
    plt.savefig(plot_file_name)

    # close figure
    plt.close(fig)
```

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Just use `axes.get_ylim()`, it is very similar to `set_ylim`. From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim):

> get_ylim()
>
> Get the y-axis range [bottom, top]

Comment: is there a way to get the graph area limit, rather than the axis limit? The black bounding rectangle is slightly beyond these values.

Comment: @PeterEhrlich That's just the margins.

Comment: I find `plt.gca().get_ylim()` to be handy - no need for extra axes definition.

Comment: Alternatively, I prefer to use `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then route all my functions through either `fig` or `ax`

Comment: I had to use fig.axes[0].get_ylim(), plt.gca().get_ylim() just returns (0.0, 1.0)

Answer (score 56):

```
 ymin, ymax = axes.get_ylim()
```

If you are using the `plt` api directly, you can avoid calls to `axes` altogether:

```
def myplotfunction(title, values, errors, plot_file_name):

    # plot errorbars
    indices = range(0, len(values))
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.errorbar(tuple(indices), tuple(values), tuple(errors), marker='.')

    plt.ylim([-0.5, len(values) - 0.5])
    plt.xlabel('My x-axis title')
    plt.ylabel('My y-axis title')

    # title
    plt.title(title)

    # save as file
    plt.savefig(plot_file_name)

   # close figure
    plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Are there advantages to using the plt api directly vs using axes? I see numerous people suggest that using axes is better, but I haven't been able to nail down why.

Comment: Axes is more programatic - so for example you can build a library of functions that take and operate on axes objects.  But the `plt` object is more for just doing something quick.  So if you're tinkering, `plt` is faster.  If you're building a bigger app, axes probably best.  This has been my experience anyway.  It's overall a weird API to be honest.

Comment: The overall weird API has its roots in MATLAB. Source: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/history.html

Answer (score 27):

Leveraging from the good answers above and assuming you were only using plt as in

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

then you can get all four plot limits using `plt.axis()` as in the following example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  # fake data
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6]

plt.plot(x, y, 'k')

xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = plt.axis()

s = 'xmin = ' + str(round(xmin, 2)) + ', ' + \
    'xmax = ' + str(xmax) + '\n' + \
    'ymin = ' + str(ymin) + ', ' + \
    'ymax = ' + str(ymax) + ' '

plt.annotate(s, (1, 5))

plt.show()
```

The above code should produce the following output plot.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just use `plt.ylim()`, it can be used to set **or get** the min and max limit

```
ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()
```

Comment: Warning: if you use axes, this solution will always return ymin=0, ymax=1. Prefer in this case  ymin, ymax = axes.get_ylim()

Answer (score 3):

I put above-mentioned methods together using `ax` instead of `plt`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(100)
y = x

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
ax.plot(x, y);

# method 1
print(ax.get_xlim())
print(ax.get_xlim())
# method 2
print(ax.axis())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Wihout defining axes:**

```
min_lim, max_lim = plt.xlim()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I don't see mentioned that, depending on the details, the `sharey` option may be able to do all of this for you, instead of digging up axis limits, margins, etc.  There's a [demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html) in the docs that shows how to use `sharex`, but the same can be done with *y*-axes.