# Seaborn (violinplot) too many y-axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I have a couple of subplots and the data are probabilities, so should (and do) range between 0 and 1. When I plot them with a violinplot the y-axis of ax[0] extends above 1 (see pic). I know this is just because of the distribution kernel that the violinplot makes, but still it looks bad and I want the y-axes of these 2 plots to be the same. I have tried set_ylim on the left plot, but then I can't get the values (or look) to be the same as the plot on the right. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When creating your [subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131607/matplotlib-get-ylim-values), set the `sharey` parameter to `True` so that both plots share the same limits for the vertical axis.

---

**[EDIT]**

Since you have already tried setting `sharey` to `True`, I suggest getting the lower and upper limits `ymin` and `ymax` from the left hand side figure and passing them as arguments in `set_ylim()` for the right hand side figure.

1) Create your subplots:

`fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (5, 5), dpi=100)`

2) Create left hand side figure here: `ax[0].plot(...)`

3) **Get** the axes limits using the `get_ylim()` method as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131607/matplotlib-get-ylim-values): `ymin, ymax = ax[0].get_ylim()`

4) Create right hand side figure: `ax[1].plot(...)`

5) **Set** the axes limits of this new figure: `ax[1].set_ylim(bottom=ymin, top=ymax)`

Comment: I should have said that I tried this and that the problem is there are 2 further axes below these that have a different scale. For that reason the `sharey` parameter doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have subplots, but I do have probabilities, and this visual extension beyond 1.0 was frustrating to me.

If you add 'cut=0' to the sns.violinplot() call, it will truncate the kernel at the range of your data exactly.

I found the answer here:
[How to better fit seaborn violinplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115637/how-to-better-fit-seaborn-violinplots)